# Band SDK doesnt seem to work from anywhere but codebehind

Tags: sdk, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

Universal App with MVVMLight.

So I started wondering why all the SDK examples were done from code behind rather than using a solid Wrapper class.

So I wanted to write a reusable wrapper class.  No luck. Even tried adding that wrapper to a ViewModel, still no luck.

Works fine from MainView.xaml.cs

```
IBandInfo[] pairedBands = BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync().Result;
            if (pairedBands.Length > 0)
            {
                using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
                {

                }
            }
```

The moment I move to any kind of OOP or View Model, ConnectAsync will never return or throw exception.  I have tried this 20 different ways, is the SDK broken?  What Is happening?  No message, no throw, just never returns.

If I throw in Code behind, wallah it works just fine and returns the client in 1/2 second.

I have spend 5-6 hours so far on this.  I wanted to create a solid wrapper class for the SDK so I could call easy calls from Model and do things like StartListener(MicrosoftBandSensor sensorToActivate).

Any suggestions?

-- For Phil's comment

I was trying to create backing variables for both client and bandinfo which would be held in a class that the VM uses.  I wrote my class as IDisposable so I could dispose of both when I was done with my wrapper.  I may be using this wrong to be honest.

```
 MicrosoftBand.MicrosoftBandClient = BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]).Result;
```

Is what I wanted to call making it a sync call since I wanted to make the calls to bandinfo and client in the constructor then hold both until the class was destroyed and just recall the vars when needed.

My VM has :

```
public BandInformation MicrosoftBand
        {
            get { return _microsoftBand; }
            set { Set(() => MicrosoftBand, ref _microsoftBand, value); }
        }
```

If they didn't pass the bandclient in the constructor I would use:

```
 private async Task InitBand(IBandInfo bandInfo)
        {

            if (bandInfo == null)
            {
                var allBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
                if (allBands.Length > 0)
                {
                    bandInfo = allBands[0];
                }
            }
            var bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(bandInfo);
            MicrosoftBandInfo = bandInfo;
            MicrosoftBandClient = bandClient;

            if (MicrosoftBandClient == null)
            {
                AddErrorMessage("This sample app requires a Microsoft Band paired to your device.Also make sure that you have the latest firmware installed on your Band, as provided by the latest Microsoft Health app.");
            }

        }
```

This seems fine working with BandInfo. I get back a solid seeming to work object For the client I get "thread exited" and nothing else.

Note: I had it in a try catch throwaway version at one point and nothing threw n exception either.

I assume you can do this like you would any other IDisposable where you handle the disposing yourself.

I can reinstantiate the BandClient each time, just figured I needed to detach the events at some point, meaning I had to keep ahold of the bandclient. I could keep it until done and would add and remove events as I needed each time.

Comment: The sample code is written from code-behind in order to demonstrate a concept in the shortest, simplest manner possible.  M-V-VM (and the like), while being better for testing and refactoring, tends to obscure the code.  Can you provide more details about how you're calling the Band SDK from your view model (or other infrastructure)?  One thing I notice in your example is calling .Result on GetBandsAsync() which is a blocking call rather than awaiting the call (as you do in the ConnectAsync()) call.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your blocking call to .Result within your VM constructor is what was causing the hang. IBandClientManager.ConnectAsync() may implicitly display UI (a Windows Runtime dialog asking the user to confirm that she wants to use that specific Bluetooth device).  If you've blocked the UI thread when it attempts to display UI, you've now gotten yourself into a deadlock.

Calling Task.Result is almost never a good idea, much less doing so within a constructor where you have little idea on which thread the constructor is executing.  If you're working with an async API (such as the Band SDK) then your best bet is to keep that interaction async as well.  Instead, defer calling ConnectAsync() until you actually need to, and do so from an async method in your VM.  (Deferring the connection is a good idea anyway because you want to minimize the time connected to the Band to preserve battery life.)  Then call Dispose() as early as possible to close the Bluetooth connection.

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you.  I was using this as a demo to IOTHUB to SA and PowerBI so didn't even think about it that way "PC's always have power" and reading the band I could just leave on if there was Bluetooth, figured all events were sent anyway it was just up to my PC to know that (turning on and off listeners). Ill go straight async and dispose for each set of calls instead of hold the client and  see if that fixes it.  I am not sure it did though. I think I tried it, I will report back.  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

So I went and looked at a bunch of examples. Finally I landed on the GravityHeroUAP demo on the MSDN site. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt573717.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I looked at his code and the source: https://github.com/kevinash/GravityHeroUWP
He was essentially doing what I wanted to do.

However, I noticed something Bizarre. In his viewmodel everything was static!

```
  public static IBandInfo SelectedBand
        {
            get { return BandModel._selectedBand; }
            set { BandModel._selectedBand = value; }
        }

        private static IBandClient _bandClient;
        public static IBandClient BandClient
        {
            get { return _bandClient; }
            set
            {
                _bandClient = value;
            }
        }
```

I ended up copying this pattern (though had to throw away my favorite MVVM lib in the process, though I am sure I can get it back).

My common pattern in my VM's:

```
  public string ExceptionOnStart {
            get { return _exceptionOnStart; }
            set { Set(() => ExceptionOnStart, ref _exceptionOnStart, value); }
       }
```

It seems to be working now!

That and I got data way too fast for the

```
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendLinesAsync(dataFile, new List<string> { toWrite });
```

Thank you for the help Phil, it got me looking in the right direction!
Thank you very, very much.  Spent WAY to long on this. Mark